# How to have multiple websites access a common directory

Tags: linux, apache

I have multiple websites on a dedicated server running under Linux/Apache.  The sites need to access common data from a directory named 'DATA' under the doc root.  I cannot replicate this directory for every site.  I would like to put this under a common directory (say /DATA) and provide a symbolic link to this directory from the doc root for each of the sites.

www/DATA -> /DATA

1. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. If I put this common directory (/DATA) directly under Linux root directory, can there be problems from Linux standpoint as the directory size can be several gigabytes and the sub directories under /DATA will need have write permissions.

Thanks

Comment: Is this directory going to be accessed through the webserver ? (eg. Http://website.com/data/file.zip) or through the filesystem (/data/file.zip) ?

Comment: It would be through the file system.  The scripts, would load files to this directory and access this directory to return content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) along with the [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) directive.  This will allow the site to access the directory via a url path.

I'm not sure what exactly it means that you'll have scripts accessing the directory to provide data.  Executing shell scripts to read an produce data is a different story entirely, but you probably want to avoid this if this is what you're doing.  Application pages could be included in the data directory and use a relative path to get to the data.  Then all sites get the same scripts and data.

I don't know what your data is, but I'd probably opt to put it in a database.  Think about how you have to update multiple machines if you have to scale your app.  Maybe the data you have is simple and a DB is overkill.

Comment: I do use Alias with the Directory directive.  Database would not be an option as the file would be document (e.g. PDF files) or media (e.g mp3 or video files).  One example of the directory access would be that a CGI script would return a media file. I can keep all the files under a common directory and provide a symbolic link to it from under the doc root of each site.  This would work. I need to understand if there is downside to keeping this directory directly under root directory and if there is a better alternative to my approach.

Comment: Keeping it under the root is likely not a problem, but it might be more appropriate to put it somewhere under /var.  If you use a symbolic link, that will shield the app from changes if you decide to change location.  (You might need more disk space and decide to place it on a new mount.)  As for permissions, I'd chown it to root:apache (where apache is the group name appropriate for your distro) and set permissions to 640 to guard against the CGI script modifying the data inadvertently.